# Range selector in Highstock.js / Angular.js doesn't update chart when xAxis configuration field is present

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have a Highstock.js chart implemented in Angular. I'm trying to have multiple zoom options for the user, with one of them selected by default. I define the buttons, I indicate which one should be selected by default (by providing index of the button), but it only works when the "xAxis" field is not present in the configuration JS object.

```
$scope.chartConfig = {  
    "useHighStocks":true,
    /*
        the line below prevents the rangeSelector from selecting
        a custom time frame option in spite of correct configuration
    */
    "xAxis": {},
    "options":{  
        "rangeSelector": {
            "allButtonsEnabled": true,
            "enabled": true,
            "selected": 1,
            "buttons": [{
                "type": 'month',
                "count": 1,
                "text": '1m'
            }, {
                "type": 'month',
                "count": 3,
                "text": '3m'
            }]
        }
        ...
```

How can I have both xAxis and custom zoom selection in the chart?

Here's the Fiddle, please try commenting / uncommenting the xAxis line and running the code.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/11zqLnh3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to put your xAxis object inside options? It looks like it will work just fine in this case:

```
    "options":{  
        "xAxis": {}, // try commenting this line

        "rangeSelector": {
    "allButtonsEnabled": true,
    "enabled": true,
    "selected": 1,
    "buttons": [{
        "type": 'month',
      "count": 1,
      "text": '1m'
            }, {
      "type": 'month',
      "count": 3,
       "text": '3m'
    }]
        },
  },
```

Look at this example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/11zqLnh3/1/